# Swift: проскроллить UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть `UICollectionView`, и я хочу проскроллить вправо к следующей секции по клику на кнопку. Как это сделать?

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4  
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //scroll to next
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {    
    cellOffset = 10
    cellWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / 3)  - (cellOffset * 4)
    cellHeight = (cellWidth / 2 * 3) + (cellWidth / 2 * 0.65)         
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
}
```

Comment: Что значит перейти? Проскроллить к началу?

Comment: @VAndrJ У меня горизонтальный скролл. После старта приложения я нахожусь в секции 0 нужно проскроллить вправо на следующую секцию. Всего их 4.

Answer (score 1):

C `UICollectionView` легко проскроллить к нужному месту:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1), at: .left, animated: true)
```

В IndexPath указываете нужные секцию/ячейку в секции. В `at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition` указываете до какой части скроллить. Так как у Вас направление горизонтальное, то `.left` - скролл к началу ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

Меняйте `collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: cellWidth * (ту ячеку которую хотите увидеть), y: 0)`

Comment: Получаю ошибку: `Cannot assign value of type 'CGSize' to type 'CGPoint'`

Comment: Простите, я не тот тип указал... поправил ответ.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/277611)

Comment: @hedgehogues вообще-то является, одним из. Просто нужно исправить названия передаваемых параметров и добавить поправку на отсутпы.